# How to change the properties of an event object stored in array based on next array input while designing calender in webpage

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

a. Have a scenario where I am trying to create a event calendar which should work in all web browser. 
Example as given below:
b. Say I add an event between 9.30 to 10.30am, so the total width of the event will be 100% in the calendar.
c. Now I add another event say between 9.45 to 11.00am, now I wanted my first event in point (b) to have a width of 50% and this new event should be moved to right by 50%.
d. Say now I again add a new event say between 10.00am to 12.00noon, all the events should have a width of 33% and the events should be arranged adjacently without any overlap and also one after the other.

1. I am trying to create the same using Java script.
2. I was able to add upto two events without any overlap.
3. But when I tried to add the 3rd event, its overlapping.
4. Had an idea of putting each element configs in an array and when I try to create the new element, thought will check in the array for the previous element configs and the place the third event.

Is there any good and easy way to design this event schedule in calendar using Java scipt ?? If there is any better approach kindly share the same.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS `flexbox`, here is an example, if you add a new item, container will adjust to the new item.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }

.flex-item {
  border: solid 1px black;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item: {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item: {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item: {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
 <div class="flex-item"><span class="counter">1</span></div>
 <div class="flex-item"><span class="counter">2</span></div>
 <div class="flex-item"><span class="counter">3</span></div>
 <div class="flex-item"><span class="counter">4</span></div>
</div>
```